# Input appears disabled in IE, but is not disabled

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8, disabled-input

I have an input (button) on my page that looks like this:

```
<input id="the-button" type="submit" class="btn" value="Click me!">
```

I am overriding the form submit action so I can check a few things before actually submitting the form. Before doing this, I disable the button, so the user doesn't click it again and so they can see that the page is working.

```
$("#the-button").attr("disabled", true);
```

If I decide that the form should not be submitted, I re-enable the button.

```
$("#the-button").attr("disabled", false);
```

This works as expected in Chrome/Firefox, but in IE8 the button *appears* to be disabled, but you can still click on it. The desired behavior is to look enabled, but it is greyed out in IE.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are using jQuery 1.6+ you should really be using .prop because 'disabled' is a property of the  [element](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_disabled.asp)

```
$("#the-button").prop("disabled", true);
$("#the-button").prop("disabled", false);
```

http://api.jquery.com/prop/

Answer (score 2):

As Wirey say is the best way using `prop`, however if you're stuck with an old version of jQuery you can "mirror" the statement for IE, so for example:

```
$("#the-button").attr("disabled", ""); // Enabled
$("#the-button").attr("disabled", "disabled"); // Disabled
```

Same goes for ReadOnly (obviously on textboxs and the like)

```
$("#the-button").attr("readonly", ""); // Read Write
$("#the-button").attr("readonly", "readonly"); // Read Only
```